# add scale information into a transformation matrix

Tags: opencv, affinetransform

```
trans_mat = [[  9.99999939e-01  -3.49065843e-04   3.60630465e-01]
             [  3.49065843e-04   9.99999939e-01  -2.60340185e-01]]

scale_factor = 1.6

final_trans_mat = ?

final_im = cv2.warpAffine(
    mat,
    final_trans_mat,
    (w, h)
)
```

How to combine `trans_mat` and `scale_factor` into one transformation matrix `final_trans_mat` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply all elements by the scale factor:

`final_trans_mat = trans_mat * scale_factor`